# What is the format of Docusign send document response's timestamp?

Tags: jquery, timestamp, docusignapi, timestamp-with-timezone

Send Envelope in docusign API sample response is shown below.

```
{
  "envelopeId": "some-id",
  "uri": "/envelopes/some-id",
  "statusDateTime": "2014-08-21T09:49:33.3470000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I want to change this `statusDateTime` as CDT. Is there any way possible to handle this in Docusign API?

If no, Is there is any possible to convert this as CDT in jQuery?

Comment: It appears to me that this timestamp is being advertised as UTC/Zulu, so it should (by design) produce the same timezone each time. I believe you would want to do any conversion to this timestamp after the fact, knowing that it is UTC so your conversion is accurate.

Comment: It would be easier to convert in the language that is making the API call. What language is that?

Comment: Hi ANdrew. I am using rails and I converted as I want. In the meanwhile I would like to convert the same from jQuery too. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above indicates, DocuSign API specifies date/time values in UTC format. It's not possible for DocuSign API responses to specify date/time using any other timezone -- it's always going to be UTC. However, it should be possible (with fairly minimal effort) to convert a date/time from UTC to CDT (or any other timezone you need) in your application code, once you receive the response from DocuSign.

Comment: Thanks Kim.Is that possible to convert timezone in jQuery ?

Comment: I'm not a jQuery expert, so I can't offer a specific code example -- but a brief search of the [jquery] tag here on Stackoverflow indicates that it is possible to convert timezone using jQuery. I'd suggest you explore those posts (i.e., search the jquery tag for 'convert timezone from UTC' or something similar).